# Extract/Parse XML data/element from BLOB column in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, groovy, plsql

I have a 2 tables, CONFIGURATION_INFO and CONFIGURATION_FILE. I use the below query to find out all employee files

```
select i.cfg_id, Filecontent 
from CONFIGURATION_INFO i, 
     CONFIGURATION_FILE f 
where i.cfg_id=f.cfg_id
```

but I also need to parse or extract data from the blob column `Filecontent` and display all cfg_id whose xml tag `PCVERSION` starts with **8**. Is there any way?

XML tag that needs to be extracted is `<CSMCLIENT><COMPONENT><PCVERSION>8.1</PCVERSION></COMPONENT></CSMCLIENT>`

XML

[image]

It need not be any query, even if it is a java or groovy code, it would help me.

**Note:** Some of the XMLs might be as big as 5MB.

Answer (score 0):

Usally you know what the data in the BLOB column, so you can parse in the SQL query..

If it is a text column (`varchar` or something like that) you can use `to_char(coloumName)`.

There are a lot of functions that you can use you can find them in this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp)

Usually you will use `to_char/to_date/hexToRow/rowTohex`

[convert blob to file link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/305876/JDBC/databases/convert-Blob-Type-File)

Answer (score 0):

So basically the data from the table `CONFIGURATION_INFO`, for the column `Filecontent` is BLOB?

So the syntax to query out the **XML from the BLOB Content** from database is using this function **XMLType**.

This function is converting the datatype of your column from BLOB to XMLType. Then parsing it using XPath function.

**Oracle Database**

```
select
 xmltype(Filecontent, 871).extract('//CSMCLIENT/COMPONENT/PCVERSION/text()').getstringval()
from CONFIGURATION_INFO ...
```

do the rest of `WHERE` logic on your own.